# Fit content to div & center, with another centered div overlapping it... but not pushing content down

Tags: html, position, center, overlapping, typography

Basically I want to have something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwtOm.png

I want the div containing the headline to fit to the size of the headlines.  I know this can be achieved with display:inline-block; or display:table-cell; but when I add another div that I want to overlap the line, it pushes everything down.

Not sure if there’s a way to avoid that or if there's a better way to get the effect I’m going for.  Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Two code examples:

```css
body,html {margin:0;border:0;padding:0; vertical-align: baseline; line-height: 1;
}

.banner {
  width:600px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color:grey;
  
}

.outer {
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:pink;
  position:relative;
}

.inner {
  display:table-cell;
  
}

.top{
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;  
}

.top, .bottom{
  padding:20px;
  text-align:justify;  
}

.overlap{
  position:relative;
  background-color:pink;
  text-align:center;
  top:65px;  
  z-index: 100;
  line-height:1;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.txty{
  font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  
  <div class="outer"> 
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="overlap"><span class="txty">AND</span></div> 
 </div> 
  </div>
  
<div class="outer">   
<div class="inner">
  <div class="top">
    <span class="txty">
Hi, this div fits to the content and it is horizontally centered, too. 
    </span>
  </div>   
  
  <div class="bottom">
    <span class="txty">
      hey cool</span>
  </div>
  
</div>
  
</div>
</div>
```

Or the other way I tried was this:

```css
body {
  background-color:grey;
  margin:0;
  
  
}

.overr {
  position:relative;
  background-color:green;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  top:43px;  
  z-index: 100;
  line-height:1;
  padding:0 10px;
  
}


.outer {
  text-align:center;
  background-color:pink;
  position:relative;
  top:20px;
}

.inner1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:green;
    line-height:0;    
}

.a{
  
  border-bottom:4px solid black;
}


.b {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:0;    
}
```

```html
  

<div class="outer">
<div class="overr">AND</div>
</div>  
  
<div class="outer">
  
<div class="inner1">
  

  
  <div class="a">
  <p>hi, this div fits to the content and it is centered, too. Cool!</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="b">
 
  <p> test</p>
  </div> 
  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `position:absolute` and adjust `top` and `left`

```
.overlap{
 position:absolute;
 background-color:pink;
 text-align:center;
 top:65px;  
 z-index: 100;
 line-height:1;
 padding:0 10px;
}
```

else apply float to the div and apply proper margins